# Is there a neater way to have a comma following a @variable in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razor display template in MVC3 for an address. Here is an example of the coding I've used for one line of the address:

```
@Model.City<text>,</text>
```

When I place the comma straight after the variable name, it creates a syntax error. Adding the <text> tag around the comma fixes the problem, but it seems a bit messy when most of the razor code is so neat and concise.

Is there a neater and more concise way to do this?

**Edit:** This piece of code is inside an if block. I didn't realise, but it turns out this affects how razar parses stuff.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>You can wrap the expression in parentheses to explicitly tell the parser where it ends:</strike>

```
@(Model.City).
```

Alternatively, you could use two expressions:

```
@Model.City@('.')
```

---

**EDIT**: I misunderstood your situation.
Inside a code block (`@if`, `@for`, `@{ ... }`), the Razor parser is expecting code, not markup (or text).

If you put an HTML tag or `<text>` tag in, it will know that you're giving it markup.
However, arbitrary text, such as `,`, is assumed to be C# source.

Instead of using the `<text>` tag to tell the parser that you're giving markup, [you should use `@:`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

```
@Model.City@:,
```

Comment: Close. I found this worked @Model.City@(",") but I also found I only have this problem when it's in an if block. Razor is wierd sometimes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Richard: I misunderstood.  See my edit.  The first part of my answer is only applicable to `.<{([`.

Comment: no it was my fault. Didn't realise the if block made things different. New version works a treat. Razor is so smart sometimes that it's hard to figure out when it doesn't do what you expect.